# Multiple variables in one form:select

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am just starting to learn Spring/MVC. I have a basic Model/Controller/JSP working.

I have a table with a few form items in it - the first row being this:

```
<div id="general">
<table>
<tr>
    <td><form:select path="systemType" items="${systemTypes}" /></td>  
</tr>
```

This works fine - the select box sends the user input using the bean that has a set method on `systemType`.

So what if I have say a `User`. They have a first name/last name in the model bean. It doesn't make sense to force someone to use two select boxes to select both their first and last name.

```
 <tr>
    <td>
    <form:select path="User" items="${users.firstName} ${users.lastName}" />
    </td>  
 </tr>
```

So I use jstl to display "First Name + Last Name". But what is the best way to take that input and put it back to my model bean where the first and last are seperated? Should I just change my model bean to show one full name, or can I do some sort of post-processing in the controller?

Comment: What happens if you have two users with the same name, both first and last? How do you distinguish them?

Comment: So, you want to get the first name and last name in one box. Just get it in one, split in your service layer the name at space and save it differently. What's the problem in that? Who has both firstname and lastname which are same. I don't know anyone like that, is that because I spend time answering users on SO or there is no one like this?

Comment: @WeareBorg. There are some `reduplicants`. You can see a few if you  also spend time at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_people_with_reduplicated_names) and [stackexchange](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94163/what-is-the-term-for-a-person-with-same-first-and-last-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [WebDataBinder](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/WebDataBinder.html) is a good/formal way to reformat/process data between viewer and controller in Spring/MVC. Also an example [here](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/spring-frameworks-webdatabinder/).

But you can simply use a setter for that (simple example, no error handling):

```
class Name {
    private String first;
    private String last;

    void setFullName(String fullName) {
        String[] parts = fullName.split(" ");
        first = parts[0];
        last = parts[1];
    }
}
```

And in the view something like this :

`<form:select path="User" items="${fullName}" />`

Spring will call a function named `setFullName` when it runs across a variable called `fullName`. The internal structure of the class is up to you.

Comment: Ok great this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the suggestion. I will implement the setFullName version for now but will try to do the WebDataBinder to learn it for the future.